# Problem figuring out correct sign using newton's third law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I'm having trouble interpreting Newton's third law on a block classic problem.

Considering a constant horizontal force acting on two blocks of masses $m_A$ and $m_B$ must give an acceleration of $a = \frac{F}{m_A + m_B}$.

I want to find the acceleration above using Newton's third law, for which I did the following:

(1) $F_{app} - F_{AB} = m_A \, a$

(2) $F_{BA} = m_B \, a$

Where $F_{AB}$ is the force that B causes on A and vice-versa.

So far so good, Newton's third law states that $F_{AB} = -F_{BA}$. But using this and substituting equation $(2)$ on equation $(1)$ gives me $a = \frac{F}{m_A - m_B}$.

*Edit:*

As pointed by the answer below, the problem with the reasoning on this case was the interpretation of Newton's third law. I stated that *"(...)Newton's third law states that $F_{AB} = -F_{BA}$(...)"*, but actually the right way to write it is $\vec{F}_{AB} = -\vec{F}_{BA}$.

Since in Equations (1) and (2) I'd already put all on x-axis component equations, third law implies that their module is equal, $F_{AB} = F_{BA}$ without the need to insert an extra sign.

Comment: Where did the minus sign in equation 1 come from?

Comment: I get the right result by adding the two equations.

Comment: Because $F_{AB}$ is opposite to $F_{app}$. The net force is then the sum of both or, in this case, the difference.

Comment: After your revision to the question, I'm not sure what you're actually asking any more.

Comment: "But using this and substituting equation (2) on equation (1) gives me (...)" I stated the wrong result I was getting, I explained the reasoning and equations that led me to the (wrong) result, in edit I recognized my error and completed the answer below.

Comment: The question has been answered as I've marked, just didn't understand the closing at all since it's not a homework or a "solve for me" problem. It's a question about how to interpret newton's third law and use it correctly when drawing free-body diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises because $F_{AB}$ is treated with two different conventions in  your solution. In eq.(1) $F_{AB}$ is considered *positive* and is subtracted from $F_{app}$ to account for its direction. In the way you've stated Newton's 3rd law $F_{AB}$ is considered *negative*. Either convention is fine, but pick one and stick to it.

For example, let's choose $F_{AB} < 0$. Then eq.(1) is modified:

$$F_{app}+F_{AB} = m_A a$$

and Newton's 3rd law remains $F_{AB} = -F_{BA}$. This convention *encodes* the direction of the force in the sign of the force.

Alternatively, you could have chosen $F_{AB}>0$ and eq.(1) remains $F_{app} - F_{AB} = m_A a$, where the minus sign must now account for the direction. In this convention, Newton's 3rd law becomes $F_{AB} = F_{BA}$, it can only compare the magnitude of the forces.

You will arrive at the expected answer in either convention, but you need to stick to one.